# 7z zip format header specifications

Tags: header, format, zip, compression, 7zip

7z zip format has two headers. One is Start header and other is end header. Start header is of 32 bytes and has 6 fields. Likewise end header has some fields which is not very clear from documentation available in 7-zio.org site. Can anyone share a clear documentation of 7z End header format.

for example, zip format : https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html

Comment: https://github.com/lvseouren/7zip/blob/master/CPP/7zip/Archive/7z/7zHeader.h from the offical implementation.

Comment: @Christoph I meant the header structure, as in the signature, compression method etc. Like local, central header and cnetral directory in .zip format